# C# Append in XML file from recursive function

Tags: c#, xml, file, recursion, append

I am trying to create an XML file containing Folder and files description.
I browse the folder content with a recursive method and I would like to append datas at each call.

Here is the code I use :

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Folders");
        ds.Tables.Add(Folder);
        ds.Tables.Add(Files);
        ds.WriteXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\FolderList.xml");
```

Could you please tell me how to proceed to add at each function call datas at the bottom of the xml file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better write the file only when all methods are over. Hold the data in memory till then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string rootPath = @"......";
XElement xRoot = new XElement("Root",new XAttribute("Path",rootPath));
RecurseDirs(rootPath, xRoot);
var xmlString = xRoot.ToString();



void RecurseDirs(string root, XElement xRoot)
{
    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
    {
        XElement xdir = new XElement("Directory",
                                        new XAttribute("Name",Path.GetFileName(dir)),
                                        new XAttribute("CreationTime",Directory.GetCreationTime(dir)));
        xRoot.Add(xdir);
        RecurseDirs(dir,xdir);
    }

    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root))
    {
        XElement xfile = new XElement("File", 
            new XAttribute("Name", Path.GetFileName(dir)),
            new XAttribute("CreationTime", File.GetCreationTime(dir)));
        xRoot.Add(xfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been able to do what I wanted with your code, thanks a lot.